# Issues removing elements, not worked correctly

Tags: css, wordpress

I have removed some elements from a wordpress theme/template, however they have not worked fully

Issue 1: Header on page still contains gray

https://www.bodyclocktherapies.co.uk/?post_type=product

Issue 2: Background image remains on mobile devices and not on desktop

https://www.bodyclocktherapies.co.uk/?post_type=product

Image: https://ibb.co/QdPc7V4

Tried some css code, but has not worked

1. Issue 1

```css
#cms-theme.woocommerce.archive #cshero-header.header-1 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}


#cshero-header-navigation.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

2. Issue 2

```css
#cms-theme.woocommerce.archive #cms-content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#cms-theme.woocommerce.single-product #cms-content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#main.site-main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I should have a complete white header and clear bacground on all devices

Comment: Useful tip - you can right click and inspect element. This should help you find the style that you have an issue with and then it will be easier to override it.  Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You need to provide code in your question to replicate the error - see how to create a [MCVE] and [can I just paste a link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply right click and used inspect element for this.

For First issue used this css:

```
#cms-theme.woocommerce.archive #cshero-header.header-1 > .container,
#cms-theme.woocommerce-page.archive #cshero-header.header-1 > .container {
      background-color: #fff;
}

#cms-theme.woocommerce.archive #cshero-header.header-1, 
#cms-theme.woocommerce-page.archive #cshero-header.header-1 {
    background-color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 993px){
 #cshero-header.header-1:before {
    background-color: #fff !important;
 }
}
```

For Second issue:
Background image come in after selector so that you need to hide that in mobile using media query

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
   #cms-theme.woocommerce #page:after,
   #cms-theme.woocommerce-page #page:after {
      display: none
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The first issue is still there, I removed the original code, and replaced with yours. The header is now more grey. https://www.bodyclocktherapies.co.uk/?post_type=product

Comment: The Cart page on mobile doesn’t seem to be taking the media code?

Comment: Essentially, I want the cart to fit in the screen like the other pages